# Where can I get a reference for the JS objects/Functions when writing SP in Azure DocumentDB

Tags: javascript, azure, stored-procedures, reference, azure-cosmosdb

Where can I get the list of functions and object to use in Azure DocumentDB Stored Procedure ?

How to delete, create, search...
For example, I manage to fish this one "collection.queryDocuments" in the internet, but is there a place that all is gathered ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is probably what you are looking for:

- [Server-side API Docs](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/)

These might also have the information that you need:

- [Write a simple stored procedure and more details on sprocs, UDFs, and triggers](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/#example-write-a-simple-stored-procedure)
- [Example stored procedures on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js/tree/master/server-side/samples/stored-procedures)
- [JavaScript language integrated queries (server-side)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/#javascript-language-integrated-query-api)

Here is the complete annotated list of links that I use as references, but note that I'm doing mostly Node.js work so I don't have a lot of information about .NET programming in here. Server-side is the same though so those aspects will be useful for you. Feel free to edit/add to this answer if you know of any.

- [Client-side API Docs](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-node/)

  This is what you used when calling DocumentDB from Node.js. Note, if you want to submit pull requests to fix errors here do not submit them to https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js rather submit them to https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node. Browse the latest source code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/tree/master/source/lib)
- [Server-side API Docs](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/)

  This is the API available to the Stored Procedures, User Defined Functions, and Triggers that are executed in DocumentDB.* [HTTP status codes for Documentdb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783364.aspx). Apparently, this is not comprehensive. I've heard of 503 and other errors that are not listed here.
- [Say goodby to self links and use ids to retrieve documents](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/)
- [JavaScript language integrated queries (server-side)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/#javascript-language-integrated-query-api)
- [Query examples and playground](http://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo)
- [Limits](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-limits/)
- [User Voice for DocumentDB](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb)
- [SQL Cheat Sheet](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query-cheat-sheet/)
- [Write a simple stored procedure and more details on sprocs, UDFs, and triggers](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/#example-write-a-simple-stored-procedure)

  Note, I no longer use triggers. The requirement to explicitly specify them when doing an operation made me worry that someone else on the team would neglect to specify them and we'd have data integrity issues. All modifications to data, I now do through sprocs. Also, it looks like you can't specify triggers inside of a sproc which makes their use an either/or choice and sprocs are more flexible.
- [Example stored procedures on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js/tree/master/server-side/samples/stored-procedures)

  Count.js is interesting because it returns a continuation token that allows it to be called many times to process very large data sets.
- [Best practices for multi-tenancy using DocumentDB](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/12/03/scaling-a-multi-tenant-application-with-azure-documentdb-2/)

  This is outdated since the introduction of partitioned collections.
- Performance Tips: [Part 1](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/20/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-1-2/) and [Part 2](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/27/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-2/)

Comment: Maybe I should post another question for this, is there a way to write the server js code some where else than the Azure portal, an IDE that include IntelliSense and a way to fast run the SP against the DB ?

Comment: Sure. You can write them in your Javascript IDE and use the API to upload or cut and paste into the portal. I suspect there is a way to get Intelliscence to know the server-side API. Maybe just reference stubs of the server-side API code.

Comment: Also there is documentdb-mock for testing server-side code.